# Print bash array of arrays to certain format

Tags: linux, bash

I have a bash array as follows:

```sh
fruits=(
F001 "Sour fruit" 5
F002 "Sweet fruit" 15
F003 "Good fruit" 10
)
```

I want to access this array and print it as follows:

```
Fruit code: F001, Desc: Sour fruit, Price: 5
Fruit code: F002, Desc: Sweet fruit, Price: 15
Fruit code: F003, Desc: Good fruit, Price: 10
```

I tried the following code, But it's giving me a wrong output

```sh
for f in "${fruits[@]}"; do
    IFS=" " read -r -a arr <<<"${f}"

       code="${arr[0]}"
       desc="${arr[1]}"
       price="${arr[2]}"
       echo "Fruit code: : ${code}, Desc: ${desc}, Price: ${price}"
       echo
done
```

Anyine know how to do this :)

Comment: What output is it giving you? how does it differ from what you expect?

Comment: bash arrays can not contain nested arrays as elements. It's not clear to me what you want to achieve.

Comment: run `typeset -p fruits` (or `declare -p fruits`) to see what's really in your array; as kvantour has noted ... you should see 9 items in the array, not the 3 you're expecting

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The bash array you define does not have 3 elements, but 9. So you can quickly do this with a modulo 3 operation:

```
for ((i=0;i<"${#fruits[@]}";i=i+3)); do
  code="${fruits[i]}"
  desc="${fruits[i+1]}"
  price="${fruits[i+2]}"
  echo "Fruit code: : ${code}, Desc: ${desc}, Price: ${price}"
done
```